# <p> is displayed under <img> tag without <br>

Tags: html, css

```html
<img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d1/d1a6cabea45b1f34f639b4f3dba8dd7af91072d4.jpg"><p>text 1</p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<p>text 2</p>
```

My text1 and text2 are going under the image but I didnt use `<br>` tag.
Is there any way to do this: 'img here' 'text1' 'text2' ?
Thanks.

Comment: Simply add display inline block

Comment: Show your html and css

Comment: A paragraph (`<p>`) is a block element. Block elements render above or below other content. If you want to change that then either use css to change the `display` of the clock element to `inline` or `inline-block`, or have the image contained inside the paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Following css for this

```
img, p {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your css

```css
img{
  display:inline;
}
p{
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d1/d1a6cabea45b1f34f639b4f3dba8dd7af91072d4.jpg"><p>text 1</p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<p>text 2</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS property called `display:inline` could be used !

```
 <img src=".."/>

 <p style="display:inline">text1</p>

 <p style="display:inline">text1</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to always use a class and assign your styles to the class rather than to an element directly. This gives you better control over which element to apply a particular style to.

```css
.my-img,.text1,.text2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<img class="my-img" src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d1/d1a6cabea45b1f34f639b4f3dba8dd7af91072d4.jpg"><p class="text1">text 1</p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<p  class="text2">text 2</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Float is the right way to do this.

```css
img {
  float: left;
  padding-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<img src='http://placehold.it/220x220'>
<p>
 Some text here. 
</p>

<p>
 Some more text to follow. 
</p>
```

And this is not only my opinion. A quote from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp):

> In its simplest use, the float property can be used to wrap text
>   around images.